# Install MPICH on CentOS error could not determine the size of a Fortran INTEGER

Tags: centos, mpi

I followed the this [installation guide](http://www.slothparadise.com/how-to-setup-mpi-on-centos-7-2-connected-virtual-machines-part-2/) to install MPICH on my machine. I got the following error while `configure`:

```
configure: error: Unable to configure with Fortran support because configure could not determine the size of a Fortran INTEGER. Consider setting CROSS_F77_SIZEOF_INTEGER to the length in bytes of a Fortran INTEGER
```

Here is the [full output and config.log file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nil20czwqnscgz5/AAAloDuohyvF2eQz0-dKAv-pa?dl=0)
Thanks for any guide o comment.

Comment: Will you be using MPICH with Fortran?

Comment: No I use C++ and C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you won't be using MPICH with Fortran, you might as well disable Fortran support:

```
$ ./configure --disable-fortran
```

or

```
$ ./configure --enable-fortran=none
```

Don't forget to also add any other options that you originally used, e.g.,

```
$ ./configure --disable-fortran --prefix=some/directory
```

Comment: Any way I still have error in  `make`, `make[2]: *** [src/mpltrmem.lo] Error 1, make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1`

Comment: @Abolfazl According to [this email](http://lists.mpich.org/pipermail/discuss/2014-November.txt), you may want to add `--without-valgrind` to the invocation of `configure`... But it would be easier to install a packaged version for CentOS. I'm not on CentOS, so I don't know where this may be found though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I needed Fortran. Compiling with a few different MPI libraries finally led to the clue (thanks, openmpi): I had gcc/gfortran installed in /usr/local, but /usr/local/lib64 and /usr/local/lib where not in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The error message for mpich and mvapich2 doesn't make sense, but it went away after setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: While that may work, the preferred way is to pass the correct options to configure.